# How to make a not uniformly convergent function, uniformly convergent?

Tags: real-analysis

For the problem F<sub>n</sub>=$\frac{nx}{1+nx}$ on [0,∞), if the interval was changed to (0,∞) it would not converge uniformly. I am confused about how to change the interval so that it does converge uniformly. I am aware in this case that the zero is what is causing the issue but how could one change a function that does not converge uniformly to converge uniformly?

From my knowledge, taking out the point that is causing the issue will not do anything but rather some sort of open ball around it will?

Answer (score 1):

On $[a, \infty)$ (where $a>0$) we have $|\frac {nx} {1+nx}-1|=\frac 1 {1+nx} \leq \frac 1 {1+na}$ and $\frac 1 {1+na} \to 0$ so $\frac {nx} {1+nx} \to 1$ uniformly.

Comment: would the same thing you did be done for (0,∞) but in this case we would have minus zero instead of minus 1? Also, I think I understand it when done out but lets says I did not know that [0,∞) would converge uniformly with that given function. What is the logical or steps i would take to esentially get rid of the issue which is in this case 0. @Kavi Rama Murthy

Comment: @SherienHassan A long as the domain contains some interval around $0$ we cannot expect uniform convergence. This is because if $x \to 0$ and $n \to \infty$ we can draw no conclusion as to how the product $nx$ behaves.

Comment: so in the case where we see a point is causing a function to not converge uniformly, we need to take an open ball around the point which would result for lets say the point a>0 and would no longer include the point making it uniformly convergent? @Kavi Rama Murthy  Doest this mean that both intervals [0,∞] and (0,∞) are not uniformly convergent?

Comment: @SherienHassan True, the sequence does not converge uniformly in either of the intervals $(0,\infty), [0\infty)$.